# AJAX call not failing or succeeding

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest, jsonp

I am trying to get data from this AJAX call, the error function is called, but I can't figure out why? Debugging me shows that the `GET` works correctly.

Is there something I'm missing from here?

The API key can be regenerated, not a security risk for me.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/christchurch_ranbats_1_melee/participants.json?api_key=UgPJ6Le4jATPLCvRpm0YirZDCX6JvMp13I6MmEVW",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("It works");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Sorry, could not fetch the data.");
    }
});
```

Comment: The response isn't [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/) -- it doesn't include the necessary "*padding*" for the format. To try `dataType: "json"`, the service will have to respond with appropriate [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Both of these options require the API/service to offer support. If it doesn't, the request may not be possible client-side where the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) applies.

Comment: Note: The 3rd argument to the `error` handler will be the `errorThrown`. You can inspect this to get started with debugging. You can also check the "Console" in your browser's developer tools. Ajax related errors are generally logged there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Jonathan, it was exactly that. Same origin policy does apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using? Later versions of jQuery use `error` instead of `failure`.

I ran your code, and it said the client blocked the request.

Comment: It was as simple as that, however the reason why it errors is the new question. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it errors because AJAX needs to be called on the same protocol, so try it on HTTPS.

Comment: It's probably because the API he's calling doesn't support JSONP, it's returning regular JSON.

Comment: I've found why this error occurs and this answer helped me in finding that so it get the tick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724894/processing-a-json-from-challonge-api